# php (nginx) can't handle more than a certain numbers of ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, nginx

I'm trying to implement a simple web page that will regularly fetch data from the web server. I'm using nginx, PHP and AJAX. It works well, but after 500 AJAX calls the web server doesn't respond (PHP crash) and I don't know why. Here is a very simple example to reproduce the problem (AJAX call every 10ms)

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Ajax Call demos</title>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/flot/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      var totalCounter = 0;

      function fetchData() {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'dynamicData.php', // simple <?php echo 1; ?>
          success: function(data) {
            $("#result").html("<p>Ajax Calls : " + totalCounter + "<br/></p>");
            totalCounter++;
          },
          dataType: 'text',
        });
        setTimeout(fetchData, 10);
      };
      fetchData();
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="result">
    result
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I go to that page, I can see the calls increasing until the number of calls reach 499, and then the webserver does not respond to anything until I restart php server.

Here is the error I have in the nginx logs :

> upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond) while reading response header from upstream, client:
>   127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /flot/essai/dynamicData.php HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "127.0.0.1", referrer:
>   "http://127.0.0.1/flot/essai/ajaxBug.html"

I've tried to change the timeout, but the problem it the same, it crashes after 500 calls.

What could be the problem and how to fix it ?

Comment: `It works well, but after 500 ajax calls, the webserver doesn't respond (php crash) and I don't know why` It's simply because you're flooding your own server with 500 requests in 5 seconds. You are DDOSing yourself. This is exactly why AJAX polling is a really bad idea. If you need to keep the UI and the server data in sync, use Websockets.

Comment: Agree with @Rory, the main problem seems to be the general approach ... But if the problem persists even with higher timeout values, then it sounds like you simply run into the maximum number of simultaneous connections allowed per server settings. You have not shown us what your PHP script you are making the AJAX requests to does, but it sounds like the connection might not be closed properly - so try and explicitly do that as soon as possible, and if you are using sessions, also use session_write_close as soon as possible and see if that changes things.

Comment: I can't use websocket because I have to keep compatibility with Internet Explorer 7 (webbrowser embedded), but I agree, it should be the right solution.
The php in this examples is just :
   <?php
     echo 1;
    ?>
How to explicitly close the connection ?

Comment: @mazipha You can switch to long-polling AJAX.  If you use Socket.IO under Node.js, it supports long-polling AJAX as a transport, which will work on IE 7 while giving you the benefits of a nice interface for modern browsers as well.

Comment: The problem is the same with longer timeout.
I've just notice that I don't have this problem with an quick installation of easyPhp (I think it uses Apache). A work around could be to use an apache webserver instead of nginx, but maybe I will face the same problem later.